# How can I compare metrics between a branch and master as part of pull request checks?

Tags: ruby, git, github, rake, travis-ci

I have a ruby library which 'measures' a text file and dumps the measurements to a file. I use Travis CI to show these results whenever someone makes a pull request to change the file in a github repo. My goal is to make a pass/fail check based on whether metrics are 'Improving'.

When a pull request is submitted and Travis CI runs my rakefile, I want to compare my metrics in the pull request branch to the metrics of the master branch.

Assume I have a rake task which runs metrics on a text file and spits out the results, and that I can compare two result files.

```
task :run_metrics
    ruby "lib/metered_object.rb"
    @metered_object= MeteredObject.new(File.expand_path("./list.txt"))
    @metered_object.set_targets({"metric1" => 10, "metric2" => 500})
    @metered_object.display_metrics >> pull_request_output

    @metered_object.compare_metrics(pull_request_output.txt, old_metrics_output.txt)
end
```

How should I use git and rake to either store and retrieve **old_metrics_output.txt**, or generate a new metrics file for master, in order to compare the newly created pull request metrics to it?

Bonus points if there's a common name for this pattern/practice I have yet to discover.

Answer (score 1):

Travis CI pulls only the specific branch you are testing, so in a PR build of branch `feature` to `master`, `git checkout --branch=feature ...` is done in the start of the build.

If you want to compare to `master`, you would need to fetch the master branch as well. This could probably be achieved by `git fetch --branch=master --depth=3`.

After that, you can use the normal tools you need to make the compare.

Please note that if you are on a private repository, the credentials used to clone the repository initially, will have been removed at the moment where you can `fetch`. If that is your case, have a look at the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/) for possibilities to authenticate your interaction with GitHub.